# Can I run a VPN server with certificates only, and no password/pre-shared keys?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I've seen [several](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/L2TPServer) writeups [around](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/AndroidVPNServer) discussing VPN server configuration.  In all of them, there are 2 or 3 pre-shared keys / passwords used at various levels of the tunnel -- one for IPSec, one for L2TP, one for PPP.

This seems silly.  I've always been of the opinion, why use a (relatively) tiny, insecure password when you can use a software token of arbitrary length?

At best, though, I've seen the suggestion to use `racoon` to handle certificate-based authentication at the IPSec layer.  That still leaves 2 other layers to worry about.  Can I do better?  If not, would it be possible / secure to omit the PSK at 2 of the 3 layers and still restrict use to authorized accounts?

I'm specifically looking for something that works well cross-platform, with both mobile and desktop clients.  I'm also more concerned with IP masquerading than security, so "best" encryption is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

When you are open to other VPN Solutions i would recommend an OpenVPN setup, it is much easier to configure, supports certificate authentication and there are plenty of clients for all platforms.

[OpenVPN Website](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html)

it ships with easyrsa3 for easy PKI management.

[Easy-RSA PKI Setup](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/EasyRSA3-OpenVPN-Howto)

With this PKI Setup you can generate the clients for the server and all clients and distribute them in pkcs12-format

It is much easier to setup and maintain than any IPSec implementation i have seen so far.